# Ошибка "No such file or directory"(Android)

Tags: java, android

не получается сохранить файл Pdf.
Вот мой код:

```
public void stringtopdf(String data) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
    String extstoragedir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File fol = new File(extstoragedir, "pdf");
    File folder = new File(fol, "pdf");
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        boolean bool = folder.mkdir();
    }
    try {
        final File file = new File(folder, "sample.pdf");
        FileOutputStream fOut;
        file.createNewFile();
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new
                PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(100, 100, 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        canvas.drawText(data, 10, 10, paint);


        document.finishPage(page);
        document.writeTo(fOut);
        document.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("error(for file)", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.omen.serverforcofe" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



        <activity
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: В какой строке ошибка происходит? Почему вы не проверяете ответ `mkdir()`?

Comment: @iksuy, mkdir возвращает false, ошибка, как я понял происходит здесь:
 final File file = new File(folder, "sample.pdf");

Comment: Если возвращает false, то mkdir не создает директорию и все остальное не имеет смысла делать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File fol = new File(extstoragedir, "pdf");
File folder = new File(fol, "pdf");
if (!folder.exists()) {
    boolean bool = folder.mkdir();
}
```

Вы не создаете директорию по переменной `fol`, а сразу хотите создать `folder`
Поскольку `fol` отсутствует, у вас создание не происходит, и возвращается false.
Если с правами у вас всё в порядке, то замена `folder.mkdir()` на `folder.mkdirs()` вам поможет

Comment: А разве 
"String extstoragedir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File fol = new File(extstoragedir, "pdf");" 
не создает директорию?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШтин файл и директории это разные вещи. Невозможно положить в коробку предмет, если этой коробки нет. Коробка, в данном случае, директория, а предмет - это файл.

Comment: @ЕвгенийШтин, нет, не создает, `File` - это всего лишь "виртуальный" объект, не имеющий никакой связи с файловой системой. Взаимодействие происходит во время IO операций. Кстати, `createNewFile` не обязательно вызывать, в вашем случае как только вы запишите первый байт в `FileOutputStream` он автоматически создастся, либо перезапишется, если ранее существовал.